# What "text:s" means?

Tags: opendocument

I parse content.xml and faced `<text:s text:c="3"/>` within *office:spreadsheet -> table:table -> table:table-row -> table:table-cell -> text:p*.
What do "text:s" and it's attibute "text:c" mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"text:s" means "spaces" and "text:c" means "count", so tag `<text:s text:c="3"/>` means "3 spaces" e.i. "   ".

Comment: Thanks for the answer. A remaining mystery, however, is why Microsoft word (latest versions as of 2018) sprinkle `<text:s/>` quite randomly throughout the **.odt** files it writes, instead of just using the space character `' '` itself.

Comment: @GlennSlayden If the preceding character is the space character, then `<text:s/>` is the second of two space characters. (See the specification [here](http://docs.oasis-open.org/office/v1.2/cd05/OpenDocument-v1.2-cd05-part1.html#a_6_1_3__text_s_).)